# Piwik: how to get a list of unique domains tracked in one site

Tags: matomo

Someone had the bad idea to put the same Piwik tracking code on many different domains.

How can I compile a list of unique domain names out of Piwik?

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer via Twitter:

The full URL is tracked and visible in visitlog. To block those unwanted requests check this faq: https://piwik.org/faq/how-to/faq_21077/

Source: https://twitter.com/richardmastop/status/846772768922353664